# How to fix Android Studio's corrupted dark (aka Darcula) mode?

Tags: android-studio

When I try to use dark mode in Android Studio, it's looking like this image. I've tried restarting Android Studio and restarting my mac, but nothing seems to help. Light mode works fine. Anyone seen this before??? I'm running Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1. built on August 17, 2023.

[image: corrupted Android Studio screen]

Comment: I noticed the issue affects other themes as well. However, with the light theme, the white issue shown above is displayed on top of the normal white background, so you don't notice it until you select all of your text.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I had accidentally set one of my project's images to be Android Studio's background image.  To fix, search Android Studio's settings for "background" and then tap the "Background Image..." button under Appearance / UI Options.  Select whatever image you want and set the opacity to 0.